# SAS - Creating a Numbered Range List of character variables?

Tags: variables, sas

I can create a Numbered Range List of numeric type, but not character type.

My code is similar to this:

```
DATA TestDataset;
    INPUT a1-a3 $;
    DATALINES;
    A   B   C
    ;
RUN;
```

This produces 3 variables - [a1], [a2] and [a3] as expected. However [a3] is character, but [a1] and [a2] are numeric. This leaves me with missing values as per the following table:

```
a1  a2  a3
.   .   C
```

The following code works, but obviously it does not scale nicely.

```
INPUT a1 $ a2 $ a3 $;
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use the hyphen notation on the length statement to get what you want. You really should use a length statement regardless..otherwise it defaults to $8.

```
DATA TestDataset;
 length a1-a3 $20;
 INPUT a1-a3 ;
 DATALINES;
 A   B   C
 ;
RUN;
```

Comment: +1 Just tested it - this works.  I like your solution better than mine :-)

Comment: This works perfectly. You are right, I should have used a `LENGTH` declaration - I'm still a bit new to SAS, so thanks a lot for this help.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a macro solution:

```
%MACRO var_list_char (var_prefix, n);
    %LOCAL i ;

    %DO i = 1 %TO &n;
        &var_prefix&i$
    %END;   
%MEND;


DATA TestDataset;
    INPUT %var_list_char (a, 3);

    DATALINES;
        A   B   C
    ;
RUN;
```

I wish I could find a way to do this without macros - I will keep digging for a bit and will update this post if I find more.  In the meantime, the above approach will definitely work.

**UPDATE 1**:  @carolinajay65's solution above is the correct non-macro approach.

**UPDATE 2**:  There is another way that I found.

```
DATA TestDataset;
    INPUT (a1-a3) ($);
    DATALINES;
    A   B   C
    ;
RUN;
```

More documentation of the language features supporting this technique can be found [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0f9yk6pd4znukn1rlw6hzkg1url.htm), in the section labeled "How to Group Variables and Informats".

Comment: I've accepted _CarolinaJay65_'s answer above, but I've given you +1 for the link and for the variable group brackets syntax, which is very nice to know.

Comment: Thanks from me as well for the variable group syntax!  Good to know.

Comment: nice to learn a new way to use the input statement. however, without a length, attrib, or format statement only the first 8 bytes will be read.